# Ошибка запуска flask сервера

Tags: python, flask

Только начинаю изучать python. Написала очень простой код и уже получила список ошибок

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

При втором коде ошибок нет, но и сервер не запускается

```
from flask import Flask

app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=56296)
```

mako обновила, компьютер латиницей переименовала. В чем может быть проблема?

Код ошибки:

> File "C:\Users\Kristina\Desktop\Новая папка (7)\lib\socketserver pv",
> line 466, in server_bind self. socket. bind(self. server_address)
> OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом,
> запрещенным правами доступа Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Windows. Открытие сокета права администратора хочет.

Comment: У Вас происходит борьба файрвола в системе с Вашим кодом. Ошибка не в коде, а в настройках операционной системы.

Comment: @GrAnd вовсе не обязательно с правами администратора запускать. Есть другие пути решения.

Comment: @GrAnd открывала pyCharm в режиме администратора, не помогло

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич подскажите, пожалуйста, какие?

Comment: Этот порт не занят другим процессом (например, предыдущим экземпляром вашей программы)?

Comment: @GrAnd проверила через консоль. Не занят

Comment: @Xrystya например открыть необходимый порт через браудмауэр Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема.

Вот этот код почему-то запустился, а предыдущие 2 варианта у меня тоже не работают.

```
app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```